# What is the size of the front axle nut of the Supercycle Hooligan?

Tags: tire, wheels, rims, axle

I was riding my bike one day and saw my font wheel axle nut on the right disappeared.

I tried to find replacements but none of them fit, I don't know the size of the nut so I cannot find one that fits. I got some nuts that were similar size, but they were 24t so it didn't fit, online people are selling 24t and 26t so I think mine is 26t but I am not sure.

The bike is a Supercycle Hooligan with 24" tires. Measurements preferred in mm but inches is fine too.

Btw, if I cannot find any online is it a good idea to 3d print them? I have a 3d printer and I can print in PLA or PETG but not sure if plastic would be a good idea to hold the front wheel in place.

Comment: Lightly grease the end of the axle, make a plaster cast of the end, carefully unscrew the plaster, and take it to a hardware store to be compared to bolts in the bins.  Or simply haul the bike into the hardware store and find the right nut in the bins.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Or just detach the remaining axle nut and take the wheel...

Comment: If you only lost the right and side, then then take the left nut into a hardware store or bicycle store and find a replacement.It's a supercycle so it's likely something super common.  If you don't have any nuts, just bring the wheel with you and you should be able to find one that fits.

Answer (score 3):

The zero-information answer is that you should take the bike to a bike shop. Axle nuts are, as far as I'm aware, a pretty standard size; a bike shop will be able to figure out what size you need and will probably just give you a replacemnt nut. Buy something to make it worth their while.

> Measurements preferred in mm but inches is fine too.

That's not how it works. If it's a metric size, you need a metric size; if it's an Imperial/American size, you need an Imperial/American size. It's not enough to say "Oh, half an inch is about 12mm and however-many threads per inch is about this number of threads per centimetre."

> Btw, if I cannot find any online is it a good idea to 3d print them? I have a 3d printer and I can print in PLA or PETG but not sure if plastic would be a good idea to hold the front wheel in place.

No, no, one hundred times no! Not remotely strong enough.

Comment: It's also highly doubtful that one could 3d print the fine internal threads with sufficient accuracy.